# New hash from array of hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, inject

The objective of the code below is to produce a hash with the keys being the `:id` field of
the hashes in `original_array`, and the values being all elements in `original_array` which have that `:id`.

```
original_array = [
  {:id => '123', :name => 'test'},
  {:id => '123', :name => 'another test'},
  {:id => '456', :name => 'yet another test'}
]

new_hash = {}
original_array.each do |a|
  new_hash[a[:id]] = original_array.select {|x| x[:id] == a[:id]}
end
```

My code does that, but there must be some better way to do it, ideally where the hash can be created in one step. If anyone can suggest and explain one (in the hope that I might improve my understanding of this sort of thing), then it would be appreciated.

Comment: Your local variable `a` is misleading. That is usually used for an array. For a hash, you should use `h`.

Comment: Noted. Presumably that is because each element from original_array is a hash, whereas I chose the letter based on the class of original_array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it

```
new_hash = original_array.group_by{|h| h[:id]}
```

Documentation: [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.omniref.com/ruby/2.1.1/classes/Enumerable##group_by).

Comment: Why the end `Hash::[]` is needed, as `#group_by` is giving you the `Hash` already ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit yes, you observed it correctly, group_by would return a hash object only.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: Hm, it used to return array of arrays, or my memory fails me.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What you are thinking, is correct for `#partition` method.. +1

Comment: Very interesting - it was not aware of that particular method. I expect that it will come in handy.